# Unmerge some image from background - Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

I am usually using either Photoshop or Illustrator. But now I got a Sketch file and wanted to export some images. All exporting was easy except I am not sure how I can unmerge an icon merged with a white background.

The icon is Black with a text bellow (splash screen) and the background is all white. How I can select the icon and text below and create a new layer from it? Or slice, I think layers are called slices, if I am not mistaken (have been using Sketch for a few days only).

For example, in Photoshop I can select this icon by color (black) and Photoshop will select all black objects. After then I export selected to a new layer. This is what I want to achieve.

PS. The reason for this is that I want to export splash image as image only and not the whole screen (image + background).

Answer (score 2):

so, since your question does not provide enough information about the file, I'll try to answer as many scenarios as I can think of.

Scenario 1 - Exporting 1
If there is a background layer that was included in the file, you can go back to the sketch file, disable/delete anything in the background, and export the screen.

[image]

Scenario 2 - Export 2
You could have a background color assigned to the artboard. So - select the artboard, make sure the background isn't selected, and export.

[image]

Scenario 3 - If someone has flattened the whole screen to one image (so it's not the icon, the text, and a background color, as it should be. 
 - If you can mask out the shape and recreate the same text - go for it
 - You can go through Photoshop and do it
 - You can quickly download GIMP and use color to alpha to get rid of the background with one click. I've created a tutorial over here: https://medium.com/@bobottle/design-tip-single-color-images-with-transparency-113e83495ca9

In any case, when asking questions, more information on your situation (including images, screenshots, etc. would be very helpful to the rest of us.

Hope I helped :)

Comment: Sketch has a magic wand tool as well, it's not amazing but can do some work for simple shapes. (Select the bitmap, select 'edit' and select the magic wand tool on the right side.)

Comment: Agreed, BUT - just like any other "magic" tool out there, it's not perfect (does especially poorly when it comes to anti-aliasing). So if someone is trying to isolate text.. oh well.. Also - you can currently only fill the selection with another color.

Comment: you can delete the background by pressing backspace, I don't need to fill it with a color. It becomes transparent as well.